# Local Taylor Expansion at each point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

> for $f\in \mathcal{C}^{\beta}$, denote by $F$ the local Taylor expansion of $f$ of order $\beta$ at each point

Does this mean that, for some fixed point $x$, we have
$$F(a) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}+...+\frac{f^{(\beta)}(a)(x-a)^{\beta}}{\beta !}?$$ Because in that case, doesn't the definition of $F$ depend on the point $x$ which is chosen? Can anyone tell, from the context, what the author means?

See http://www.hairer.org/notes/Regularity.pdf, page 12 (last two lines) for context

Comment: It is $F(x)$ not $F(a)$, I presume.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But then won't $F(x)$ depend on the choice of $a$?

Comment: I did not go to the paper. Sorry fot not having the time now. I shall look at it tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: The local Taylor expansion *depends* of the point.

Comment: Exactly...from the context, can you tell what the author means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, for $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\beta}$, $F(x)$ is defined to be
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{i=\lfloor \beta\rfloor}\frac{f^{(i)}(x)}{i!}X^i.$$

This way, as $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\beta}$, we do indeed have
$$\|F(x)-\Gamma_{xy}F(y)\|_{\lfloor \beta\rfloor}=|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{(\lfloor \beta \rfloor)!}|\lesssim |x-y|^{\beta-\lfloor\beta\rfloor}.$$

For lower orders,
\begin{align*}\|F(\mathbf{x})-\Gamma_{\mathbf{xy}}F(\mathbf{y})\|_{\alpha}&=\left|\sum_{|\mathbf{i}|=\alpha}\frac{f^{(\mathbf{i})}(\mathbf{x})}{\mathbf{i}!}-\sum\limits_{|\mathbf{i}|=\alpha}^{\lfloor\beta\rfloor}\frac{f^{(\mathbf{i})}(\mathbf{y})}{\mathbf{i}!}\sum_{|l|=0}^{|i|}\binom{i}{l}({x-y})^{{i-l}}\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{|\mathbf{i}|=\alpha}\frac{f^{(\mathbf{i})}(\mathbf{x})}{\mathbf{i}!}-\sum\limits_{|\mathbf{i}|=\alpha}^{\lfloor\beta\rfloor}\frac{1}{\mathbf{i}!}\sum_{|j|=0}^{\lfloor\beta\rfloor-|i|}\frac{f^{(\mathbf{i+j})}(\mathbf{y})}{j!}({x-y})^{{i-l}}\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{|\mathbf{i}|=\alpha}\frac{1}{\mathbf{i}!}\left(f^{(\mathbf{i})}(\mathbf{x})-\sum\limits_{|\mathbf{i}|=\alpha}^{\lfloor\beta\rfloor}\frac{1}{\mathbf{i}!}\sum_{|j|=0}^{\lfloor\beta\rfloor-|i|}\frac{f^{(\mathbf{i+j})}(\mathbf{y})}{j!}({x-y})^{{i-l}}\right)\right|\\
&\lesssim\left|\mathbf{x-y}\right|^{\lfloor\beta\rfloor-\alpha+1}\\
&\lesssim\left|\mathbf{x-y}\right|^{\beta-\alpha},\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The full quote is

> for $f \in \mathcal C^\beta$, denote by $F$ **the element in $\mathcal D^\beta$ given by** the local Taylor expansion of $f$ of order $\beta$ at each point.

This is important because $\mathcal D^\beta$ is actually a much bigger set than you think: an element $F \in \mathcal D^\beta$ assigns to each $x \in \mathbf{R}^d$ a polynomial $F_x$ of degree less than $\beta$. In particular, the set of *all* local Taylor expansions of $f$ of order $\beta$, at *all* points of $\mathbf{R}^d$, is an element of $\mathcal D^\beta$.

The full definition of $\mathcal D^\beta$ is Definition 2.9 on p.6. It also includes a condition that says that an element $F \in \mathcal D^\beta$ can't just assign arbitrary unrelated polynomials to each point $x \in \mathbf R^d$: the polynomials $F_{x_0}(x - x_0)$ and $F_{x_1}(x - x_1)$ have to be approximately consistent with each other.

This is exactly what a Taylor series does. For example, if $f(x) = \sin x$ and we take $\beta=6$, then $F$ will assign to the point $0$ the polynomial $$F_0(t) = t - \frac{t^3}{6} + \frac{t^5}{120}$$ and to the point $\pi$ the polynomial $$F_\pi(t) = -t + \frac{t^3}{6} -\frac{t^5}{120}.$$
These are not *exactly* equal: $F_\pi(x - \pi)$ is a complicated polynomial along the lines of
$$\left(\pi - \frac{\pi^3}{6} + \frac{\pi^5}{120}\right) - x + \cdots + \frac{\pi x^4}{24} - \frac{x^5}{120}$$
which is not the same polynomial as $F_0(x-0)$. However, they're approximately consistent: because both of them are approximations to $f(x)$, as $\beta$ increases, the coefficients will get closer to each other.

Comment: P.S. I used *most* of the same notation in the paper, but slightly different notation for elements of $\mathcal D^\beta$: the paper would write as $F(x_0)$ what I write as $F_{x_0}$. I avoided this because the paper's notation here is extremely confusing, but you should be aware of the difference.

Comment: so you're saying that, from the definition of $\mathcal{D}^{\beta}$, we'll get $\|F_x(t-x) - \Gamma_{xy}F_y(t-y)\|_{\beta} \lesssim |x-y|^{\beta}$?

Comment: 1) Almost: when we have $\alpha$ in the norm, we have $\beta-\alpha$ in the exponent. (So when we have $\beta$ in the norm, we'd get $|x-y|^0$ on the other side, and don't get very much of a bound.)

Comment: 2) Also, you're a step ahead: from the definition of $\mathcal D^\beta$, we get $\|F_x(t) - \Gamma_{xy} F_y(t)\|_\alpha \lesssim |x-y|^{\beta-\alpha}$. But (I think this follows from Definition 2.5) we have $\Gamma_{xy} F_y(t) = F_y(t+x-y)$, so we can rewrite that as $\|F_x(t) - F_y(t+x-y)\|_\alpha \lesssim |x-y|^{\beta-\alpha}$.

Comment: Ok @Misha, but now isn't $F_y(t+x-y)$ going to be $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\beta}\frac{f^{(i)}(y)(t-2y+x)^i}{i!}$?

Comment: yeah, but that's what I mean - if $t$ gets replaced by $t+x-y$ and $x_0$ is $y$, then in the sum we will have $(t+x-y-y)^i$

Comment: Oh, I see. That's a sign mistake on my part: I think we want to replace $t$ by $t+y-x$ instead, then.

Comment: Ok, now that makes sense to me, because for example at order $\lfloor \beta \rfloor$ we will get $\frac{f^{(\lfloor \beta \rfloor}(x)-f^{(\lfloor \beta \rfloor}(y)}{\lfloor \beta \rfloor !}$ which, as $f\in \mathcal{C}^{\beta}$, is $\lesssim |x-y|^{\beta-\lfloor \beta \rfloor}$. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you're interested, I've filled in the details in my answer (below), for which I got some help from my supervisor